# get both simcard operator name in dual SIM mobile

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I want to know Both sim card's operator name when mobile is dual sim.In single SIM I got operator name programmatically But For duel SIM I can't although after so many search and try.

**If I run My app in dual sim phone than I can get both sim card operator name in my app For example : Idea,Vodafone.**

**EDIT:**

Is anyone know How to get sim operator name of IMEI no then I have IMEI no.

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button btnOne, btnTwo;
TextView tvInfo;
Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOne);
    btnTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTwo);
    tvInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvInfo);

    TelephonyInfo telephonyInfo = TelephonyInfo.getInstance(this);

    boolean isDualSIM = telephonyInfo.isDualSIM();
    boolean isSIM1Ready = telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready();
    boolean isSIM2Ready = telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready();

    TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    try {
        telephonyInfo.imsiSIM1 = telephonyInfo.getDeviceIdBySlot(context,
                "getSimSerialNumberGemini", 0);
        telephonyInfo.imsiSIM2 = telephonyInfo.getDeviceIdBySlot(context,
                "getSimSerialNumberGemini", 1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String number = manager.getLine1Number();

    String optName1 = getOutput(getApplicationContext(), "getCarrierName", 0);
    String optName2 = getOutput(getApplicationContext(), "getCarrierName", 1);

    final String carrierName = manager.getSimOperatorName();
    tvInfo.setText(" " + isDualSIM + " " + optName1 + " " + optName2 + " "
            + telephonyInfo.imsiSIM1 + " " + telephonyInfo.imsiSIM2 + " "
            + number + " " + isSIM1Ready + " " + isSIM2Ready);

    btnOne.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    btnTwo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if (carrierName.equalsIgnoreCase("TATA DOCOMO")
                    || carrierName.contains("DOCOMO")) {
                startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, USSD.class));
                String ussdCode = "*" + "111" + Uri.encode("#");
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri
                        .parse("tel:" + ussdCode)));
            } else if (carrierName.equalsIgnoreCase("!dea")
                    || carrierName.contains("idea")) {
                startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, USSD.class));
                String ussdCode = "*" + "121" + Uri.encode("#");
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri
                        .parse("tel:" + ussdCode)));
            } else if (carrierName.equalsIgnoreCase("AIRTEL")
                    || carrierName.contains("airtel")) {
                startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, USSD.class));
                String ussdCode = "*" + "123" + Uri.encode("#");
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri
                        .parse("tel:" + ussdCode)));
            }

        }
    });

}

private static String getOutput(Context context, String methodName,
        int slotId) {
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    Class<?> telephonyClass;
    String reflectionMethod = null;
    String output = null;
    try {
        telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
        for (Method method : telephonyClass.getMethods()) {
            String name = method.getName();
            if (name.contains(methodName)) {
                Class<?>[] params = method.getParameterTypes();
                if (params.length == 1 && params[0].getName().equals("int")) {
                    reflectionMethod = name;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (reflectionMethod != null) {
        try {
            output = getOpByReflection(telephony, reflectionMethod, slotId,
                    false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return output;
}

private static String getOpByReflection(TelephonyManager telephony,
        String predictedMethodName, int slotID, boolean isPrivate) {

    // Log.i("Reflection", "Method: " + predictedMethodName+" "+slotID);
    String result = null;

    try {

        Class<?> telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass()
                .getName());

        Class<?>[] parameter = new Class[1];
        parameter[0] = int.class;
        Method getSimID;
        if (slotID != -1) {
            if (isPrivate) {
                getSimID = telephonyClass.getDeclaredMethod(
                        predictedMethodName, parameter);
            } else {
                getSimID = telephonyClass.getMethod(predictedMethodName,
                        parameter);
            }
        } else {
            if (isPrivate) {
                getSimID = telephonyClass
                        .getDeclaredMethod(predictedMethodName);
            } else {
                getSimID = telephonyClass.getMethod(predictedMethodName);
            }
        }

        Object ob_phone;
        Object[] obParameter = new Object[1];
        obParameter[0] = slotID;
        if (getSimID != null) {
            if (slotID != -1) {
                ob_phone = getSimID.invoke(telephony, obParameter);
            } else {
                ob_phone = getSimID.invoke(telephony);
            }

            if (ob_phone != null) {
                result = ob_phone.toString();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        // Log.i("Reflection", "Result: " +  e.printStackTrace());
         return null;
    }

    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ofcourse you can get the details of dualsim in mobiles below version 22. It is only not officially supported only after 22.

```
private static String getOutput(Context context, String methodName, int slotId) {
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    Class<?> telephonyClass;
    String reflectionMethod = null;
    String output = null;
    try {
        telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
        for (Method method : telephonyClass.getMethods()) {
            String name = method.getName();
            if (name.contains(methodName)) {
                Class<?>[] params = method.getParameterTypes();
                if (params.length == 1 && params[0].getName().equals("int")) {
                    reflectionMethod = name;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (reflectionMethod != null) {
        try {
            output = getOpByReflection(telephony, reflectionMethod, slotId, false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return output;
}

private static String getOpByReflection(TelephonyManager telephony, String predictedMethodName, int slotID, boolean isPrivate) {

    //Log.i("Reflection", "Method: " + predictedMethodName+" "+slotID);
    String result = null;

    try {

        Class<?> telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());

        Class<?>[] parameter = new Class[1];
        parameter[0] = int.class;
        Method getSimID;
        if (slotID != -1) {
            if (isPrivate) {
                getSimID = telephonyClass.getDeclaredMethod(predictedMethodName, parameter);
            } else {
                getSimID = telephonyClass.getMethod(predictedMethodName, parameter);
            }
        } else {
            if (isPrivate) {
                getSimID = telephonyClass.getDeclaredMethod(predictedMethodName);
            } else {
                getSimID = telephonyClass.getMethod(predictedMethodName);
            }
        }

        Object ob_phone;
        Object[] obParameter = new Object[1];
        obParameter[0] = slotID;
        if (getSimID != null) {
            if (slotID != -1) {
                ob_phone = getSimID.invoke(telephony, obParameter);
            } else {
                ob_phone = getSimID.invoke(telephony);
            }

            if (ob_phone != null) {
                result = ob_phone.toString();

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    //Log.i("Reflection", "Result: " + result);
    return result;
}
```

Use this two methods. You have to get all sim details by using **Java reflection**.

Now get the detail you want by just using a single line of code.

```
String optName = getOutput(context, "getCarrierName", 0);
```

the first param is the **context**.
second param is the method name you wanna access and the third param is the slotId. "0" means sim **1**.

> All the result of this method will be string. Convert them as per your
>   need.

Each mobile having its own method. Like micromax is having method like "getCarrierNameGemni". Don't worry, The code I gave you will handle everything for you. If it cant get the result, it will return null. Happy coding!

Comment: In both SIM it returns null

Comment: Which mobile you are using?

Comment: moto e2 2nd gen

Comment: Any log you got?? stack trace?

Comment: in "getOpByReflection" uncomment the "e.printStackTrace()" line in "catch" and try again, There should be some log if null output. Try again and tell me if any logs. If null again without logs, Then I will revise the code.

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getDeviceIdGemini [int]

Comment: also null in lenovo k3 note

Comment: ok, You are calling it like "String optName = getOutput(context, "getCarrierNameGemni", 0);" ??

Comment: No..as you suggested

Comment: I placed the "getCarierName" for just example. You have to use "getSimOperatorName"

Comment: Thats ok, The sim details can be read is the sim state is ready. Check your sim is in ready state. use "getSimState" and tell me the result of the sim state

Comment: Actually it is an optional field. If the Operator didn't want to set the operator name in their sim. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6570810/4804264 WIll work with other sims.

Comment: In some device this is not working but I accept your answer because you helped me a lot..I found a way..now i will do it

Comment: Please try "getSimOperatorNameForPhone" method instead. It worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

Since API version 22 its possible

try following code for device having os greater than android 5.1

```
List<SubscriptionInfo> subscriptionInfos = SubscriptionManager.from(getApplicationContext()).getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
for(int i=0; i<subscriptionInfos.size();i++)
{
    SubscriptionInfo lsuSubscriptionInfo = subscriptionInfos.get(i);
    Log.d(TAG, "getNumber "+ lsuSubscriptionInfo.getNumber());
    Log.d(TAG, "network name : "+ lsuSubscriptionInfo.getCarrierName());
    Log.d(TAG, "getCountryIso "+ lsuSubscriptionInfo.getCountryIso());
}
```

for more information : [Documentation: SubscriptionManager - Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager.html#getActiveSubscriptionInfoList%28%29)
Hope it helps. Peace.

Comment: Below 22 can't get I Both operator name?

Comment: @ibtehaz it's 5.1 not 5.2

Comment: You can use Android's Telephony manager, however, this will return only one result (the currently active sim in the network). From API 22, you can get the both using SubscriptionManager class

Comment: @Prashant, Thanks. My bad

Comment: check it <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31468108/how-can-i-get-the-service-provider-name-of-other-phone-numbers-in-contacts-list>

Comment: @KrishnaJ, Here is a link > http://stackoverflow.com/a/18782517/5876080 < they used Telephony Manager class for both sim card. I am not sure whether it will work.

Comment: Both link can not give operator name for both sim.I already tried it.

Comment: @KrishnaJ, Then I guess you cannot before API 22.

Comment: many application are already working below 22 and do some work like this.

Comment: @KrishnaJ, custom hack I suppose. Not that it's impossible. It's actually more like, there is no EASY way I guess.

Comment: @ibtehaz reading comment from link you commented , i found original answer , may be this code is device dependent , here is that link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim/17499889#17499889

Comment: @KrishnaJ Read original answer , may be that helps

Comment: @prashant i already done it my app and get bot imei no like this.But for SIM operator this is not working

Answer (score 5):

For API >=22:

```
{
        SubscriptionManager subscriptionManager = (SubscriptionManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE);

        List<SubscriptionInfo> subscriptionInfoList = subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();

        if (subscriptionInfoList != null && subscriptionInfoList.size() > 0) {
            for (SubscriptionInfo info : subscriptionInfoList) {
                String carrierName = info.getCarrierName().toString();
                String mobileNo = info.getNumber();
                String countyIso = info.getCountryIso();
                int dataRoaming = info.getDataRoaming();

            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

For any android device. This may help you. try this!

```
   //above 22
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 22) {
        //for dual sim mobile
        SubscriptionManager localSubscriptionManager = SubscriptionManager.from(this);

        if (localSubscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoCount() > 1) {
         //if there are two sims in dual sim mobile
            List localList = localSubscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
            SubscriptionInfo simInfo = (SubscriptionInfo) localList.get(0);
            SubscriptionInfo simInfo1 = (SubscriptionInfo) localList.get(1);

            final String sim1 = simInfo.getDisplayName().toString();
            final String sim2 = simInfo1.getDisplayName().toString();

        }else{
         //if there is 1 sim in dual sim mobile
            TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

            String sim1 = tManager.getNetworkOperatorName();

        }

    }else{
        //below android version 22
                TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext()
                        .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

                String sim1 = tManager.getNetworkOperatorName();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution is too curious and It is only work in motoe2.not in others.In some it display null or in some only display one sim operator.

**Just change this two line:**

```
telephonyInfo.optName1 = telephonyInfo.getOutput(
            getApplicationContext(), "SimOperatorName", 1);
    telephonyInfo.optName2 = telephonyInfo.getOutput(
            getApplicationContext(), "SimOperatorName", 2);
```

getOutput() method is as per answer of **Sujith**.