# Get operators name sim card

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I write simple widget. I want to get the names of operators on a dual sim phone I am trying to use the *SubscriptionManager* class. My actions:

Setting permissions:

```
<uses-permission android: name = "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android: name = "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Attempting to use *getActiveSubscriptionInfoList* method to get all sims:

```
@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    super.onEnabled(context);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission (context, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)! = 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT> = Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
           SubscriptionManager subscriptionManager = SubscriptionManager.from (context.getApplicationContext ());
           List <SubscriptionInfo> subsInfoList = subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList ();

           Toast.makeText (context, subsInfoList.size (), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show ();
           // ... etc
        }
    }
}
```

The *getActiveSubscriptionInfoList* method always returns an empty collection. Why is this happening? My configuration: Huawei device P30, Android 10.0, Android Studio 4.0.1.

Comment: Similar (or duplicate) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565646/get-both-simcard-operator-name-in-dual-sim-mobile)?

Comment: Does this {https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565646/get-both-simcard-operator-name-in-dual-sim-mobile} solve your query?

Comment: @MattF.;
@segfault404 
The answer works, but I'm wondering why doesn't it function the class SubscriptionManager?